# FFmpeg HEVC compression?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression

I'm part way through a video processing program and am using ffmpeg to read a frame, process it and then write it to an output file. Input files are HEVC codec and are currently being read and then written to a HEVC mp4 output file. I've noticed that the output file size is an order of magnitude smaller than the input - I assume this means that the video has been compressed again.

What output format/codec should I be using to ensure that the data is not being compressed a second time?
Can I output as HEVC but disable the compression?

Comment: What is the processing?

Comment: @Gyan Audio Visual processing. I'm piping go pro footage into python and editing the frames based on audio data streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `C` in `HEVC` stands for **c**ompression. So writing to a HEVC stream will always involve compression.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @Gyan and verified I didn't remember correctly: In reallity The `C` in `HEVC` stands for (en)**c**oding. What stands is, that encoding in this context is ment as **lossy encoding** and thus compression

If you want to output uncompressed frames, you can use e.g. `rawvideo`, but remember that this is a headerless format, so you need to care for the metadata (geometry, color space) seperately or pack it into e.g. an AVI container.

You might also want to consider an **editing** codec (such as ProRes) a.o.t. a **transport** codec (such as HEVC), as it will create files in a more handleable size than real losless video, but with very little visible loss after multiple decompression/compression cycles.

Comment: Great thanks for the reply. The source footage is coming from a go pro so I can only get hold of it with a transport codec. The rawvideo worked with an AVI container, however, I've realised that the end goal for me would be uploading to youtube or social media. This means that I'll need to convert back to h265/4 to upload anyway. I've found the -crf option and it seems to allow adjustment of compression so I'll be fine-tuning that.

Comment: The `C in HEVC stands for **coding**.

Comment: @Gyan I stand corrected, edited my answer

Comment: Well, HEVC does support lossless coding.

Comment: @Gyan: I beg to differ. HEVC does allow bypassing DCT and quantization, but it does not allow bypassing color space transformation. This implies, that nonlinear RGB inputs (as are very common in the broadcast industry) will color-shift, as the transport colorspace is linear. This effect is visible to the naked eye. Only linear RGB inputs will allow a bit-identical, i.e. losless encoding in HVEC. And, yes: This linearisation is a compression, as it reduces the amount of bits necessary to transport a **nearly** identical picture.

Comment: Lossless coding means that the input raster is bit-identical to the output raster. Any processing of the raster before encoding or after decoding are not germane to whether HEVC allows lossless coding. That signaling is what VUI is for.

Comment: @Gyan sorry you are wrong here. HVEC "losless" is bit-identical only for selected color spaces, that's exactly the point. All broadcast-quality color spaces can not be transported via HVEC in a losless way.

Comment: Share a specification of a pixel format that HEVC doesn't allow lossless encoding for, e.g. `yuv420p10le`

Comment: @Gyan: Broadcast-type cameras run a **non-linear** rgb12 to rgb24 color space. The non-linearity means, that any function mapping this color space to anyting that HEVC can handle  (including yuv420p10le, which in itself is by far too lose) is not bijective. While in theory external color spaces are possible, there is basically no support in currently available hard/software. I understand, that this is not a very common use case, but it isn't exotic either: You want the clothes of talk show guests to look exactly the same color after a cut to a different cam.

Comment: This has gotten further away from the claim at hand, which is in lossless coding, the decoder emits what the encoder receives. Nothing you've said demonstrates a HEVC counter-case. All the common standards (NTSC/ATSC/PAL/DVB) use a non-linear transfer function, even sRGB - videos encoded with linear light are rare. Any conversion to an encoder-supported format or from a decoder-emitted format to end-state is outside the scope of the coding standard. The rounding or gamma transfer errors would occur even in an original --> mezzanine --> original pipeline leaving out the compressor entirely.

Comment: @Gyan, I am sorry you lack the fundamentals to understand the problem - you seem to mix up the layers randomly. So I'll just leave it a that. Suffice to say, that the bitstream created by a modern broadcast industry camera can not bei transported via HVEC without losses.

Comment: Maybe you can link to an article or industry forum that explains this issue.